# How to make 3D model from spot elevation geodetic map

Tags: geometry-nodes, point-clouds

I need help, and I could not find the answer anywhere, so if anyone knows how to do it, please tell me.

First of all, I know there are probably better tools to do this. But I would like to do it in Blender if it is possible or rational at all. My skills in Blender are very basic, but I am planning to learn it more.

I have a geodetic survey in PDF:
[image: geodetic survey]

And I would like to create a 3D model of it. Can someone please recommend steps on how to do it?

Comment: Hello do you have a greyscale image? You would use it as height map

Comment: If your only data is this "dead" map, without a file with (X,Y,Z) coordinates, you will have to enter those values one at a time. The "brute force" steps might be: (1) Import the picture as a plane. (2) In Edit mode, top view, add one vertex and move it at a spot position to set (X,Y). (3) Enter its elevation as Z. (4) Select vertices by set of 3 and make a face. (5) Save as often as you can ! You can use the top-left scale in the PDF file to rescale your data now in Blender.

Comment: @moonboots - no, I just have this vector image/pdf :(  Thank you for your interest in helping.

Comment: An other way is to start with a basic plane (4 vertices), or a triangle (a circle with 3 points). Move these vertices to 3 or 4 spot positions. Then extrude new vertices and move these to adjacent spot positions. Edit Z coordinate afterwards.

Comment: @StefLAncien - Thank you very much. The "brute force" approach is an option for me, but due to my lack of knowledge of Blender I had to ask if there was a better way.

Thank you again.

Comment: I wonder if maybe AI could be used to convert the image to a list of coordinates... For example, here the AI will detect text: https://portal.vision.cognitive.azure.com/demo/extract-text-from-images and in JSON output give the x y coordinate, and of course text. For most points, the actual point would be a little bit to the left and down of the bottom-left bounding box corner. The text value would then become the z coordinate. So this process can be automatized for the most part.

Comment: thank you @Markus von Broady, z coordiante is not a problem OCR can do that, i will try and check if AI can get x,y coordinets from the image right